# Can't process SOAP response

Tags: java, parsing, soap, response

I have the following code:

```
SOAPConnectionFactory sfc = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
          SOAPConnection connection = sfc.createConnection();

          MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
          SOAPMessage sm = mf.createMessage();
          SOAPHeader sh = sm.getSOAPHeader();
          SOAPBody sb = sm.getSOAPBody();
          sh.detachNode();
          MimeHeaders mimeHeader = sm.getMimeHeaders();

          //change header's attribute
          mimeHeader.setHeader("SOAPAction", "\"urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1#GetBinaryState\"");
          //sh.addAttribute(SOAPFactory.newInstance().createName("SOAPAction", "", "urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1#SetBinaryState"),"");
          QName bodyName = new QName("urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1", "GetBinaryState", "u");

          //sm.add            

          SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = sb.addBodyElement(bodyName);
          QName qn = new QName("BinaryState");

          System.out.println("\n Soap Request:\n");
          sm.writeTo(System.out);
          System.out.println();

          URL endpoint = new URL("http://" + ipAddress + ":49153/upnp/control/basicevent1");
          SOAPMessage response = connection.call(sm, endpoint);

          connection.close();
          System.out.println(response.getContentDescription());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Giving me this response (In wireshark)

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"                    
    s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <s:Body>
        <u:GetBinaryStateResponse xmlns:u="urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1">
            <BinaryState>0</BinaryState>
        </u:GetBinaryStateResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I want to get the `BinaryState` value (0) or (1) in Java.
I'm having a hard time trying to figure out where this is located in the `SOAPMessage` response. Help would be great.  Or even if I could put the XML response in a string and parse it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn a SOAPMessage into a String, where you have

```
SOAPMessage response = connection.call(sm, endpoint);
```

Do this:

```
SOAPMessage response = connection.call(sm, endpoint);
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
response.writeTo(os);
String responseXml = new String(os.toByteArray());
// work with responseXml here...
```

## Edit:

As an alternative, if all you want is a specific value of an element you already know the name (and that at least one will exist), you may get it trough something like this:

```
String responseBinaryState = response.getSOAPBody()
                                     .getElementsByTagName("BinaryState")
                                     .item(0).getTextContent();
System.out.println("BinaryState: "+responseBinaryState);
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you so much.  Been pulling my hair out and google wasn't helping.

Comment: The XML has already been parsed, why advise to turn it back into String?

Comment: @flup You are right, I gave the `String` option based on the possibility he put on the question. I'll add an alternative without turning into `String`.

Answer (score 0):

[`response.getSOAPBody()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html#getSOAPBody%28%29) will give you a Dom node for the body, getting to its children won't be any different from navigating a normal Dom tree.

So you can navigate through the tree (untested, do debug!):

```
Node body = response.getSOAPBody();
Node binStateResponse = body.getFirstChild();
Node binaryState = binStateResponse.getFirstChild();
Node binaryStateText = binaryState.getFirstChild();
String result = binaryStateText.getNodeValue();
```

Or use an XPath expression to find the answer a bit more reliably, independent of the exact contents of the body.

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
Node body = response.getSOAPBody();
String result = xpath.evaluate(
    "//BinaryState/text()", 
    body);
```