# Parsing SOAP Response in Java

Tags: java, web-services, parsing, soap, response

I do not succeed in parsing a SOAP Response in Java (using Bonita Open Solution BPM).
I have the following SOAP response (searching for a document in the IBM Content Manager; the SOAP Response returns 1 matching document)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:RunQueryReply xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/db2/cm/beans/1.0/schema" xmlns:ns1="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/db2/cm/beans/1.0/schema">
         <ns1:RequestStatus success="true"></ns1:RequestStatus>
         <ns1:ResultSet count="1">
            <ns1:Item URI="http://xxxx/CMBSpecificWebService/CMBGetPIDUrl?pid=96 3 ICM8 ICMNLSDB16 ICCSPArchivSuche59 26 A1001001A12D18B30015E9357518 A12D18B30015E935751 14 1087&amp;server=ICMNLSDB&amp;dsType=ICM">
               <ns1:ItemXML>
                  <ICCSPArchivSuche ICCCreatedBy="EBUSINESS\iccadmin" ICCCreatedDate="2012-04-18T10:51:26.000000" ICCFileName="Golem_Artikel.txt" ICCFolderPath="" ICCLastModifiedDate="2012-04-18T10:51:28.000000" ICCLibrary="Dokumente" ICCModifiedBy="EBUSINESS\iccadmin" ICCSharePointGUID="c43f9c93-a228-43f9-8232-06bdea4695d1" ICCSharePointVersion="1.0   " ICCSite="Archiv Suche" cm:PID="96 3 ICM8 ICMNLSDB16 ICCSPArchivSuche59 26 A1001001A12D18B30015E9357518 A12D18B30015E935751 14 1087" xmlns:cm="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/db2/cm/api/1.0/schema">
                     <cm:properties type="document">
                        <cm:lastChangeUserid value="ICCCMADMIN"/>
                        <cm:lastChangeTime value="2012-04-18T11:00:15.914"/>
                        <cm:createUserid value="ICCCMADMIN"/>
                        <cm:createTime value="2012-04-18T11:00:15.914"/>
                        <cm:semanticType value="1"/>
                        <cm:ACL name="DocRouteACL"/>
                        <cm:lastOperation name="RETRIEVE" value="SUCCESS"/>
                     </cm:properties>
                     <cm:resourceObject CCSID="0" MIMEType="text/plain" RMName="rmdb" SMSCollName="CBR.CLLCT001" externalObjectName=" " originalFileName="" resourceFlag="2" resourceName=" " size="702" textSearchable="true" xsi:type="cm:TextObjectType">
                        <cm:URL value="http://cmwin01.ebusiness.local:9080/icmrm/ICMResourceManager/A1001001A12D18B30015E93575.txt?order=retrieve&amp;item-id=A1001001A12D18B30015E93575&amp;version=1&amp;collection=CBR.CLLCT001&amp;libname=icmnlsdb&amp;update-date=2012-04-18+11%3A00%3A15.001593&amp;token=A4E6.IcQyRE6_QbBPESDGxK2;&amp;content-length=0"/>
                     </cm:resourceObject>
                  </ICCSPArchivSuche>
               </ns1:ItemXML>
            </ns1:Item>
         </ns1:ResultSet>
      </ns1:RunQueryReply>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would like to get the filename (**ICCFileName="Golem_Artikel.txt"**) and the url to this file ( <**cm:URL value="http://cmwin01.ebusiness.local:9080/icmrm/ICMResourceManager/A10**...) in string Variables using Java. I read several articles on how to do this ([Can't process SOAP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389943/cant-process-soap-response) , [How to do the Parsing of SOAP Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997680/how-to-do-the-parsing-of-soap-response)) but without success. Here is what I tried:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

// Clean response xml document
responseDocumentBody.normalizeDocument();
// Get result node
NodeList resultList = responseDocumentBody.getElementsByTagName("ICCSPArchivSuche");
Element resultElement = (Element) resultList.item(0);
String XMLData = resultElement.getTextContent();

// Check for empty result
if ("Data Not Found".equalsIgnoreCase(XMLData))
    return null;


DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
inputSource.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(XMLData));
Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(inputSource);
Node node = doc.getDocumentElement();
String result =  doc.getNodeType();


return result;
```

From Bonita, I only get responseDocumentBody or responseDocumentEnvelope (org.w3c.dom.Document) as webservice response. Therefore, I need to navigate from the SOAP Body to my variables. I would be pleased if someone could help.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a lot of work with this, I would definitively recommend using JAXB as MGoron suggests. If this is a one shot excersize, XPATH could also work well.

```
    /*
     * Must use a namespace aware factory
     */
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(...);


    /*
     * Create an XPath object
     */
    XPath p = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    /*
     * Must use a namespace context
     */
    p.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {

        public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }

        public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }

        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            if (prefix.equals("ns1"))
                return "http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/db2/cm/beans/1.0/schema";
            if (prefix.equals("cm"))
                return "http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/db2/cm/api/1.0/schema";
            return null;
        }
    });

    /*
     * Find the ICCSFileName attribute
     */
    Node iccsFileName = (Node) p.evaluate("//ns1:ICCSPArchivSuche/@ICCFileName", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    System.out.println(iccsFileName.getNodeValue());

    /*
     * Find the URL
     */
    Node url = (Node) p.evaluate("//ns1:ICCSPArchivSuche/cm:resourceObject/cm:URL/@value", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    System.out.println(url.getNodeValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

1. get RunQueryReply schema
2. map xsd to java classes using jax-b
3. unmarshall response string to jax-b class object

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to do this in [VTD-XML](http://sdiwc.us/digitlib/journal_paper.php?paper=00000582.pdf), it basically consists of 2 XPath queries, each returning one result... however the code is robust as it doesn't assume those queries will return non-empty result...

```
import com.ximpleware.*;

public class parseSOAP {
    public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException, Exception{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        vg.selectLcDepth(5);// soap has deep nesting so set to 5 to speed up navigation
        if (!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\soap2.xml", true))
            return;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap =new AutoPilot(vn);

        //declare name space for xpath
        ap.declareXPathNameSpace("ns", "http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/db2/cm/beans/1.0/schema");
        ap.declareXPathNameSpace("ns1", "http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/db2/cm/beans/1.0/schema");
        ap.declareXPathNameSpace("cm", "http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/db2/cm/api/1.0/schema");
        ap.declareXPathNameSpace("soapenv", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");


        ap.selectXPath("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns1:RunQueryReply/ns1:ResultSet/ns1:Item/ns1:ItemXML//ICCSPArchivSuche/@ICCFileName");
        int i=0;
        if ((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            System.out.println("file name ==>"+vn.toString(i+1));
        }

        ap.selectXPath("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns1:RunQueryReply/ns1:ResultSet/ns1:Item/ns1:ItemXML//ICCSPArchivSuche/cm:resourceObject/cm:URL/@value");
        if ((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            System.out.println("file name ==>"+vn.toString(i+1));
        }
    }
}
```