# How to parse the soap response data in android

Tags: java, android, xml, wcf

i am called wcf webservice from android.i am getting the response string is following.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body><ProcessResponse xmlns="http://venture-easy.com/Core/ServiceManager">
<ProcessResult xmlns:a="http://venture-easy.com/Core/BaseResponse" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:BaseResponse i:type="b:LoginResponse" xmlns:b="http://venture-easy.com/Security/LoginResponse">
<a:IsSuccess>false</a:IsSuccess>
<a:OffSetMinutes>0</a:OffSetMinutes>
<a:TimeTrace xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<c:string>StartProxy 04/01/2014 04:36:24.405 PM</c:string>
<c:string>StartServiceHandle04/03/2014 09:37:00.049 PM</c:string>
<c:string>StartBaseHandle04/03/2014 09:37:00.068 PM</c:string>
<c:string>EndHandle4/3/2014 9:37:03 PM</c:string>
<c:string>EndBaseHandle04/03/2014 09:37:03.015 PM</c:string>
<c:string>EndServiceHandle04/03/2014 09:37:03.015 PM</c:string>
</a:TimeTrace><a:result>Error</a:result>
<b:Account i:nil="true" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PlexiTech.Application.Entity.Core.Model"/>
<b:Bookmark i:nil="true" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PlexiTech.Application.Entity.Core.SystemService.Model"/>
<b:ContractDetail i:nil="true" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PlexiTech.Application.Entity.Booking.Model"/>
<b:DefaultView i:nil="true" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PlexiTech.Application.Entity.Core.Model"/>
<b:IsAccountActivated>false</b:IsAccountActivated>
<b:IsAgreementAccepted>0</b:IsAgreementAccepted>
<b:IsAuthorizedForMobileAccess>false</b:IsAuthorizedForMobileAccess>
<b:IsCorporateContracts>false</b:IsCorporateContracts>
<b:IsPasswordExpired>false</b:IsPasswordExpired>
<b:IsPasswordReset>false</b:IsPasswordReset>
<b:IsUserActivated>false</b:IsUserActivated>
<b:IsValidUser>false</b:IsValidUser>
<b:MaxTaxiCompanyTieUp>0</b:MaxTaxiCompanyTieUp>
<b:Menus i:nil="true" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PlexiTech.Application.Entity.Core.Model"/>
<b:Module i:nil="true" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PlexiTech.Application.Entity.Core.SystemService.Model"/>
<b:ParentAccount i:nil="true" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PlexiTech.Application.Entity.Core.Model"/>
<b:SessionId i:nil="true"/>
<b:SubMenus i:nil="true" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PlexiTech.Application.Entity.Core.Model"/>
<b:UserContext i:nil="true" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PlexiTech.Application.Entity.Core.Model"/>
<b:UserModule i:nil="true" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PlexiTech.Application.Entity.Core.SystemService.Model"/>
<b:Views i:nil="true" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PlexiTech.Application.Entity.Core.Model"/>
</a:BaseResponse>
</ProcessResult>
</ProcessResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I am calling wcf using httppost call and getting string response like this.please tell me how to parse this response in android.i am new to this type of parsing.please tell me its very urgent.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just refer this links
         http://thiranjith.com/2012/10/15/introduction-to-working-with-ksoap2-in-android/
         [Parsing SOAP Response in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975796/parsing-soap-response-in-java)

Comment: But here i am not getting response as a soapobject.I am getting string response.if i am getting soapobject response is this example is suitable.